# Why mysql delete hanging can't work properly

Tags: mysql

```
    try {
                        JSONArray evaluations = JSON.parseArray(removeEvaluationWords);
                        for (Object evaluation : evaluations) {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) evaluation;
                            String code = (String) jsonObject.get("code");
                            String scene = (String) jsonObject.get("scene");
                            String type = (String) jsonObject.get("type");
                            boolean isSuccess = repository
                                    .remove(code, scene, type);
                            if (isSuccess) {
                                logger.info(LOGGER, "remove successfully.info={0}", jsonObject);
                            }
                        }
                        return true;

                    } catch (Throwable e) {
                        logger.error(e,  "removeEvaluationWords exception");
                        return false;
                    }


 public boolean remove(String code, String scene, String type) {
        try {
            QueryCondition condition = new QueryCondition();
            condition.setScene(scene);
            condition.setCode(code);
            condition.setType(type);

            List<InfoDO> infoDOList = InfoMapper
                    .selectByCondition(condition);
            if (CollectionUtils.isEmpty(fundEvaluationWordsList)) {
                //log here
                return true;
            }
            if (fundEvaluationWordsList.size() != 1) {
               //log here
                return false;
            }
            InfoDO infoDO = infoDOList.get(0);

            int result = infoMapper.deleteById(infoDO.getId());
            if (result != 1) {
                //log here
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log here
            return false;
        }

    }
```

I use a json array and try to remove a row one by one. But the first delete seems hang for a long time and didn't return. Select the row first if the row exists then delete the row by id. I'm sure the row isn't locked.

Comment: What is the need of checking the row? you can use this with where condition in deletion query! also, check the condition column indexing.

Comment: Hi I just want to make sure the row exists before executing delete statement. I don't understand why did it hang so long. Is anything wrong with the code?